# Cannot call a function out of an alert button

Tags: swiftui

I have got a View with a list and an onTapGesture. In onTapGestrue I call the function "doOnTap". If I do it this way (A), the function will called, the debug print statements were written to the log and everything is fine. But now I want to add an alert for asking if I really want to call this function. So I moved the code from onTapGesture to the OK alert button (B). But if I tap, I only reach the onTapGesture and the alert appears, but if I choose "ok" the function "doOnTap" was not called. I see "onTapGesture.." and "onTapGesture...ENDE" but no doOnTap. What do I wrong?

```
-- A Start --------------------------------------------
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack(alignment :.leading, spacing: 10) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Menu() {
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
            ...
            List {
                Section {
                    if matchData.count > 0 {
                        ForEach(matchData) { oneMatchDataSet in
                            let index = matchData.firstIndex(of: oneMatchDataSet)!
                            if oneMatchDataSet.isPlaying  && oneMatchDataSet.player != nil {
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    print("onTapGesture...Start")
                                    doOnTap(index: index, matchData: self.matchData, einAus: "EIN")
                                    print("onTapGesture...End")
                                })
                                .contextMenu {
                                    Group {
                                        ...
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } // <-- ForEach
                        .onMove(perform: move)
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            ...
                        }
                    } // <-- if matchData.count
                } header: { // <-- Section
                    ...
                } // <-- Header
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                
                Section {
                    ...
                } header: { // <-- Section
                    ..
                } // <-- Header
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, isEditable ? .constant(.active) : .constant(.inactive))
        }
    }
}
-- A End --------------------------------------------
```

```
-- B Start --------------------------------------------
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack(alignment :.leading, spacing: 10) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Menu() {
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
            ...
            List {
                Section {
                    if matchData.count > 0 {
                        ForEach(matchData) { oneMatchDataSet in
                            let index = matchData.firstIndex(of: oneMatchDataSet)!
                            if oneMatchDataSet.isPlaying  && oneMatchDataSet.player != nil {
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    print("onTapGesture...Start")
                                    self.actualIndex = index
                                    self.isShowingQuestionWechsel = true
                                    print("onTapGesture...End")
                                })
                                .contextMenu {
                                    Group {
                                        ...
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } // <-- ForEach
                        .onMove(perform: move)
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            ...
                        }
                    } // <-- if matchData.count
                } header: { // <-- Section
                    ...
                } // <-- Header
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                
                Section {
                    ...
                } header: { // <-- Section
                    ..
                } // <-- Header
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, isEditable ? .constant(.active) : .constant(.inactive))
        }
        .alert("\(tmpQuestion)", isPresented: $isShowingQuestionAuswechslung) {
            if self.isWechselRunning {
                Button("Abbrechen", action: {
                    ...
                })
                Button("Ok", action: {
                    let _ = print("Hier OK Start")
                    doOnTap(index: self.actualIndex, matchData: self.matchData, einAus: "EIN")
                    let _ = print("Hier OK Ende")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
-- B End --------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre] that someone else can run?

Comment: If no actions are present, the system includes a standard ```OK``` action to dismiss the alert. In that case your function won't be called. [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:)-4rhk6)

Make sure the value of ```isWechselRunning``` is true and displaying your custom actions.

Comment: Take a look at [`confirmationDialog(_:isPresented:titleVisibility:actions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:actions:)-46zbb)

Comment: Hi. Thanks to all of your hints. isWechselRunning is true. So this is not the reason. I commented out the alert and inserted a confirmationDialog. It works fine. But I think it looks better with an alert. So I go back to the alert. In the meantime I restarted XCode 15. After go back to alert all works fine. I did no change in my code. But now it works. Is this sometimes the solution to restart XCode? I never had this behavior in XCode before. 

And what should I do with this Question in stack overflow?